# How to make my 'play' button clickable when my MediaPlayer is prepared

Tags: android, media-player

I'm building a **radio** application on **android**, I want know how to make my **'play'** button **clickable** when my `MediaPlayer` is prepared?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();

mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
         // Prepared
    }
}
```